# APPLICATION FAILED TO START error encountered on SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm self-studying in Spring boot application and encountered this problem. Weird thing is that I only followed the tutorial but still encountered this

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.Project1.service.PersonService required a bean of type 'com.example.Project1.dao.PersonDao' that could not be found.
```

I have one controller, 2 DAO files, 1 Person for model and 1 for service class.

These are my codes:

PersonController:

```
package com.example.Project1.api;

import com.example.Project1.model.Person;
import com.example.Project1.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RequestMapping("api/v1/person")
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonService personService){
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void addPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
        personService.addPerson(person);
    }
}
```

FakePersonDataAccessService

```
package com.example.Project1.dao;

import com.example.Project1.model.Person;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository("fakeDao")
public class FakePersonDataAccessService implements PersonDao {

    private static List<Person> DB = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int insertPerson(UUID id, Person person){
        DB.add(new Person(id, person.getName()));
        return 1;
    }
}
```

PersonDao

```
package com.example.Project1.dao;

import com.example.Project1.model.Person;

import java.util.UUID;

public interface PersonDao {

    int insertPerson(UUID id, Person person);

    default int insertPerson(Person person){
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        return insertPerson(id, person);
    }
}
```

Person

```
package com.example.Project1.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.UUID;

public class Person {

    private final UUID id;
    private final String name;

    public Person(@JsonProperty("id") UUID id, @JsonProperty("name") String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UUID getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

PersonService

```
package com.example.Project1.service;

import com.example.Project1.dao.PersonDao;
import com.example.Project1.model.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonDao personDao;

    @Autowired
    public PersonService(@Qualifier("mongo") PersonDao personDao){
        this.personDao = personDao;
    }

    public int addPerson(Person person){
        return personDao.insertPerson(person);
    }
}
```

I've tried googling the error but found no answer. Hope someone can enlighten me about the error encountered. Thank you~!

Answer (score 1):

You only have **"fakeDao"** qualifier class that implements `PersonDao` but your injecting **"mongo"** qualifier. As another option, you can just removed the `@Qualifier` annotation in `PersonService` constructor since you only have one class that implements `PersonDao`